# How to write in an excel on Runtime (while execution) in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I don't have any code for the problem.

I want to write in an Excel on Runtime while doing script execution,Application which i am automating will generate one request number after performing certain steps.Now,My question is- How to capture that request number while execution and put it into an excel sheet and then i have to proceed further with script execution. I have to use that request number in further script execution (on the flow after generation of request number,it has to reside inside excel and then that request number has to get use in further script execution after generation of it).I hope my question is clear, i am preferring selenium  with java code on this.
I don't have any clue on this, give me ideas what i can try for my code, it's new for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: shall i edit now in a good way?

Comment: Code is not there, i am describing my problem here, it's a new thing i incurred, so describing the issue.

Comment: Pratibha, please read the links I've sent above. They have some guidelines on how to write good questions, what will make it easier to get some help. After that, edit your question trying to make it very clear where you need help. It's common to show your effort with some existing code, to know where you're struggling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Poi jars for same.

https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Code to set the data is as below:

```
public void setXLCellValue(String sheetName,int rowNum,int cellNum, String input)
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);

        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).createCell(cellNum).setCellValue(input);

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlpath);

        wb.write(fos);

        fos.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Code to get the data is as below:

```
public String getXLcellValue(String sheetName, int rowNum, int cellNum)
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(xlpath);
        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

        return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: let me try it. Thank you

Comment: what is there in xlpath?

Comment: location of your excel in your machine like D:\\selenium java\\selenium packages\\demo.xlsx